# Adding a number to a word to call up a variable

Tags: c++

Please be nice I am a total newby.

I have a list of variables (strings) from num1 to num90. I need to call these from a function by adding the number in an int to the word num.

The task is to convert digits to words from 'jumping into c++'...I might not be going about it in the 'right' way but this part has been stopping me for a while now!!

I'm trying like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    // Hard code numbers to 20 and then in tens to 90
    string num1 = "one";
    string num2 = "two";
    string num3 = "three";
    string num4 = "four";
    string num5 = "five";
    string num6 = "six";
    string num7 = "seven";
    string num8 = "eight";
    string num9 = "nine";
```

Etc...up to 90

```
    int main ()
    {

    // Break the number down into three digit blocks
    int num = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the number: ";
    cin >> num;


  while (num > 999)
    {
int digit = (num % 1000);
num = ((num - digit)/1000);
//cout << digit << '\n';
//cout << num << '\n';

// For each block of numbers work out hundreds,


if (digit > 100)
{
    int i = digit;
    int j = (i % 100);
    cout << num.append(j) << " hundred";
}
```

What I need to happen is the number stored in 'j' to be tagged onto the word num in order to call the string num*.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you ultimately want a function like `int2words`, or what? Write some input -> output examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use a map:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::map<int, std::string> words { { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" }, { 3, "three" } };

int main()
{
    std::cout << words[1] << std::endl;
}
```

You'll probably have to deal with some special cases (up to twenty?), and you need a word for "hundred", etc. If you want to make it internationalizable, you'll have to think even harder.

Comment: I actually did this, a long time ago, and was able to generate
English, French or German just by changing the set of tables
(and a flag or two: German puts no spaces between words in a
number, and inverts the tens and units, compared to French or
English).  The units table actually had 20 entries, and the tens
table could have an empty entry, provided that the previous
entry wasn't empty; if the entry was empty, you used the
previous entry (and added 10 to the units to index it).  The
actual conversion then proceded by three digit blocks (`/ 1000`
and `% 1000`).

Comment: Oh, and you don't really want to use an `std::map` for a table indexed by small integers, do you?

Comment: I don't think it's a bottleneck.  But when the indexes are an integer from 0 to 9, somehow, `std::vector`, or in this case, simply `char const* []` or `std::string []`, seems more natural.  (For static constant arrays, I tend to use `char const*[]`, simply because they can be statically initialized.  Which avoids any issues of order of initialization.  Not that that's likely to be an issue here---just force of habit.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I appreciate the argument, but I think in the long run a map will be more flexible. For example, you can look up if a certain number has a word, and if not go and break it down further... anyway, there are lots of details in the final algorithm, so take this as just one possibility. There are certainly other options, and the simplicity of an array is also something worthwhile.

Comment: In the long run... You'll be looking up units (index [0...20)), tens (index [0...10)) and maybe hundreds (index [0..10)).  I just can't see a possibility of `map` being useful.  (In general, if the index is an `int`, _unless_ there is a strong reason to think that the array will be very, very sparse, `std::vector` is the container of choice.)

Answer (score 2):

> What I need to happen is the number stored in 'j' to be tagged onto
>   the word num in order to call the string num*.

The trouble with that approach is that any variable names you use in your code are not compiled: when the program runs it will manipulate the values of your variables, but it doesn't know or care that you decided to use the name "num3" instead of "numero3" or "foobar".

If you want to make a link between a digit (3) and a string ("three") then you can use a Vector (as [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13668853/98806) suggests, although you'll have problems after 20) or better still a Map (as [@Kerrek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13668864/98806) suggests): these will work because in both cases the strings are referenced by the *value* of a variable (eg the value of **digit** in `lookup[digit]`, or the literal value **1** in `words[1]`) rather than by the *name* of a variable.

---

EDIT:

For interest, here's a version using 'if' and 'switch'...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string units2word(int units){
    switch (units){
        case 0: return "zero";
        case 1: return "one";
        case 2: return "two";
        case 3: return "three";
        // etc ...
        case 18: return "eighteen";
        case 19: return "nineteen";
    }
}

string tens2word(int tens){
    switch(tens){
        case 2: return "twenty";
        case 3: return "thirty";
        // etc ...
        case 9: return "ninety";
    }
}

string num2words(int num) {
    if (num > 99 && num%100 == 0) return units2word(num/100) + " hundred";
    if (num > 99) return units2word(num/100) + " hundred and " + num2words(num%100);
    if (num < 20) return units2word(num);
    if (num%10 == 0) return tens2word(num/10);
    return tens2word(num/10) +"-"+ units2word(num%10);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num = -1;
    while( num < 0 || num > 999){
        cout << "Please enter a number between 0 and 999: ";
        cin >> num;
    }
    cout << "You typed: " << num2words(num) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys...I haven't got to maps or vectors as yet. I might just carry on with the book and try to solve the problem when I feel I have the right tools. Or I could just jump ahead and learn something about 'map' which looks interesting and very useful.

Comment: If you want a solution without Map, you could try using a `switch` statement, or a bunch of `if` clauses...

Comment: I was looking at using a load of `if` clauses, but it seemed far to cumbersome. The `map` method looks far more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using std::vector. This gives you a variable that takes an index

```
std::vector<std::string> lookup;
lookup.push_back( "zero" );   // starts at lookup[0]

lookup.push_back( "one" );
lookup.push_back( "two" );
// etc

// then

std::cout << lookup[digit] << std::endl;
std::cout << lookup[num] << std::endl;
```

Comment: This will break when you get to 21... (`Hard code numbers to 20 and then in tens to 90`)